# Generalized Cartesian Product

Tags: c++, c++17, template, combinatorics

Much to my chagrin, neither STL nor Boost has a cartesian product. Namely, given as arguments one or more iterables, create an iterator producing `std::tuple`s of every combination of elements (with one drawn from each iterator in the order of the arguments).

My goal here was to make `cartesian_product` to behave exactly like python's [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) (with the exception of the optional `repeat` kwarg). Ideally, it would be a zero cost abstraction (when compared to using nested for loops).

As an example:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> as = {1, 2};
std::vector<char> bs = {'a', 'b'};
std::vector<float> cs = {1.5, 2.5};

for (auto [a, b, c] : cartesian_product(as, bs, cs)) {
    std::cout << "(a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

Should produce:

```
(a = 1, b = a, c = 1.5)
(a = 1, b = a, c = 2.5)
(a = 1, b = b, c = 1.5)
(a = 1, b = b, c = 2.5)
(a = 2, b = a, c = 1.5)
(a = 2, b = a, c = 2.5)
(a = 2, b = b, c = 1.5)
(a = 2, b = b, c = 2.5)
```

To make it general and support an arbitrary number of args, I had to use parameter packs and do some template pattern matching.

Here's what I arrived at:

```
#pragma once

#include <tuple>


template<typename... Ts>
class product_iterator;

template<typename... Ts>
class product;

template<typename T>
class product<T> {
  public:
    explicit product(const T &x) : m_x(x) {}

    product_iterator<T> begin() const;
    product_iterator<T> end() const;

  protected:
    const T &m_x;
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
class product<T, Ts...> {
  public:
    product(const T &x, const Ts&... xs) : m_x(x), m_xs(product<Ts...>(xs...)) {}

    product_iterator<T, Ts...> begin() const;
    product_iterator<T, Ts...> end() const;

  protected:
    const T &m_x;
    product<Ts...> m_xs;
};

template<typename T>
class product_iterator<T> {
    friend class product<T>;

  public:
    std::tuple<typename T::value_type> operator*() const {
        return std::make_tuple(*m_it);
    }

    const product_iterator<T> &operator++() {
        m_it++;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const product_iterator &other) const {
        return m_it == other.m_it;
    }

    bool operator!=(const product_iterator &other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

  protected:
    typedef typename T::const_iterator t_iterator;

    product_iterator(t_iterator it, t_iterator end) : m_it(it), m_end(end) {}

    t_iterator m_it;
    t_iterator m_end;
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
class product_iterator<T, Ts...> {
    friend class product<T, Ts...>;

  public:
    decltype(auto) operator*() const {
        return std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(*m_x), *m_xs);
    }

    const product_iterator<T, Ts...> &operator++() {
        if (++m_xs == m_xs_end && ++m_x != m_x_end) {
            m_xs = m_xs_begin;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const product_iterator &other) const {
        return m_x == other.m_x && m_xs == other.m_xs;
    }

    bool operator!=(const product_iterator &other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

  protected:
    typedef typename T::const_iterator t_iterator;
    typedef product_iterator<Ts...> ts_iterator;

    product_iterator(t_iterator x, t_iterator x_end, ts_iterator xs,
                     ts_iterator xs_begin, ts_iterator xs_end)
        : m_x(x), m_x_end(x_end), m_xs(xs), m_xs_begin(xs_begin), m_xs_end(xs_end) {}

    t_iterator m_x;
    t_iterator m_x_end;
    ts_iterator m_xs;
    ts_iterator m_xs_begin;
    ts_iterator m_xs_end;
};

template<typename T>
product_iterator<T> product<T>::begin() const {
    return product_iterator<T>(m_x.begin(), m_x.end());
}

template<typename T>
product_iterator<T> product<T>::end() const {
    return product_iterator<T>(m_x.end(), m_x.end());
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
product_iterator<T, Ts...> product<T, Ts...>::begin() const {
    return product_iterator<T, Ts...>(m_x.begin(), m_x.end(), m_xs.begin(),
                                      m_xs.begin(), m_xs.end());
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
product_iterator<T, Ts...> product<T, Ts...>::end() const {
    return product_iterator<T, Ts...>(m_x.end(), m_x.end(), m_xs.end(), m_xs.begin(),
                                      m_xs.end());
}

template<typename... Ts>
product<Ts...> cartesian_product(Ts&... xs) {
    return product<Ts...>(xs...);
}
```

I've tested for correctness and also for speed. Both clang 6 and gcc 8 struggle to optimize this to be equivalent to nested for loops. For empirical results, see [this gist with a reproducible benchmark](https://gist.github.com/baileyparker/cc4211a06235ae719591f6c04ed7eb7c). On my machine, I consistently get around the following:

```
$ g++-8 --version
g++-8 (Homebrew GCC 8.1.0) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ clang++-6 --version
clang version 6.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_601/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin

$ make clean && CXX=g++-8 make benchmark
# ... snip ...
time ./run_cartesian
       32.53 real        32.42 user         0.03 sys
time ./run_loop
       32.39 real        32.29 user         0.03 sys

$ make clean && CXX=clang++-6 make benchmark
# ... snip ...
time ./run_cartesian
       30.31 real        30.24 user         0.02 sys
time ./run_loop
       27.30 real        27.24 user         0.02 sys
```

Not sure what's going on with gcc's timings here (hopefully this benchmark isn't borked!), but there's a noticeable difference with clang. Furthermore, looking at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/iEZqU3) for both gcc-8 and clang-6 shows both appear to be unable to optimize away some of the abstraction from `product_iterator`.

Furthermore, if you replace `dummy` with an accumulator and do an actual dot product like:

```
uint32_t dot(const std::vector<uint32_t> &as, const std::vector<uint32_t> &bs) {
    uint32_t acc = 0;

    for (auto [a, b] : cartesian_product(as, bs)) {
        acc += a * b;
    }

    return acc;
}
```

And:

```
uint32_t dot(const std::vector<uint32_t> &as, const std::vector<uint32_t> &bs) {
    uint32_t acc = 0;

    for (auto a : as) {
        for (auto b : bs) {
            acc += a * b;
        }
    }

    return acc;
}
```

The different becomes incredibly noticeable. The loop version runtime drops to about 1 second and the cartesian product remains at 30s on my machine. [Looking at godbolt for this](https://godbolt.org/g/h1HwHU) you can see very clearly that both gcc and clang are able to vectorize the nested loop version but not the cartesian version.

I'm curious about the following things:

- How idomatic is this code?
- How pluggable is this code? (ie. is it compatible with all of the contexts that it should be valid in?)

  - Have I implemented everything that I should for this iterator?
- Is there a better way to express this such that gcc and clang can better optimize loops using `cartesian_product`? Ideally, `cartesian_product` should be a zero cost abstraction (compared to nested for loops).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Naming

Using `m_x` for the container (in `product`) as well as the iterator (in `product_iterator`) gets confusing. Similar for `m_xs`.

## Performance / Optimization

The compiler relies on the "nestedness" of loops to optimize. The `product_iterator` removes this, so the compiler is unable to reason about it as perfectly.

For comparison: Clang and GCC are able to generate nearly identical (mostly some different XMM register allocation) assembly for these 2 alternatives (dot product example) as it does for the nested loops one.

#### Snippet 1

```
uint32_t dot(const std::vector<uint32_t>& as, const std::vector<uint32_t>& bs) {
    uint32_t acc = 0;

    acc = std::accumulate(
        std::begin(as),
        std::end(as),
        acc,
        [&bs](auto&& acc, auto&& a) {
            return std::accumulate(
            std::begin(bs),
            std::end(bs),
            acc,
            [&a](auto&& acc, auto&& b) { return acc + a*b; });
        });

    return acc;
}
```

#### Snippet 2

```
template<typename Callable, typename Cont>
auto cartesian_product(Callable&& op, const Cont& cont) {
    for(auto&& x : cont) {
        op(x);
    }
}

template<typename Callable, typename Cont, typename... Conts>
void cartesian_product(Callable&& op, const Cont& cont, const Conts&... conts) {
    for(auto&& x : cont) {
        cartesian_product([&x, &op](auto&&... args) { op(x, args...); }, conts...);
    }
}

uint32_t dot(const std::vector<uint32_t>& as, const std::vector<uint32_t>& bs) {
    uint32_t acc = 0;

    cartesian_product([&acc](auto&& a, auto&& b){ acc += a*b; }, as, bs);

    return acc;
}
```

## Implementation

- Prefer uniform initialization (using `{}`) over `()`.
- `product_iterator<T>::m_end` isn't needed.
- `product_iterator<T, Ts...>::m_x_end` isn't needed. (The comparison in `operator++` can be removed.)
- Members should be `private` if possible.
- Is it necessary for `product_iterator`s constructors to be `protected`? Making them `public` removes the necessity for those `friend class` declarations.
- Prefer non-member `std::begin`/`std::end` over the corresponding member functions. This allows usage of types where those member functions don't exist (e.g. C style arrays, like `int arr[4]`).

## Questions

- It generally seems OK to me.
- There are some things missing on the iterators for general usage (e.g. with standard library):

  - Type aliases `iterator_category`, `value_type`, `reference`, `difference_type` and `pointer` (used to deduce iterator traits)
  - pointer dereference (`operator->()`)
  - post increment (`operator++(int)`)
  - Usually a default constructor is provided for iterators (= end iterator).
  - Also, you might want to think about keeping a `const product<Ts...>*` in the general `product_iterator` instead of `m_xs_begin` and `m_xs_end`. After all, some other code (e.g. the one using the iterators) might modify the underlying container(s), which for some containers is well defined behavior.
- See *Snippet 2* above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I see how the naming could be confusing. I was going for the typical functional list destructuring into `(x:xs)` and carried it through to indicate how the pieces worked together, but perhaps it was too far removed. I'll take a deeper look into your snippets in a bit, but duly noted. I was hoping that clang might be able to deduce the nested loop given the similar output, but perhaps vectorization occurs earlier. Thanks for the list, I will go about fixing those!

Comment: @BaileyParker: The problem is that the compiler doesn't see the "nestedness" in `product_iterator`. `productor_iterator` produces a linear result set, so that's all the compiler can reason about. And since this result set isn't contiguous, vectorization isn't possible. (Maybe this could be improved using coroutines in the future, basically keeping the nested structure but `co_yield`ing individual combinations.

Comment: What do you think would be less confusing for `x`/`xs`. I had a hard time coming up with good concise names (`current` and `rest`?). To the points you just added: uniform initialization for both `product` and `product_iterator`? any particular reason why? You're right about `m_end`. `m_x_end` as well, it seems. The constructors could be private as well. I figured they shouldn't be public as only a `product` should be able to construct a `product_iterator`. Good tip about `std::begin` and `std::end`, I'll use them instead!

Comment: @BaileyParker: My confusion with `m_x`/`m_xs` was mostly that I couldn't tell whether it refered to the container or an element inside the container on a glance (in different contexts). Just renaming all instances of  `m_x` to`current` won't fix this. (Maybe append `_iter` to your iterator name of choice?)

Comment: Also since `std::tuple` has no members or member functions (well it has `operator=` and `swap` but neither of those make sense, right?), what is the purpose of `operator->`?

Comment: @BaileyParker: `std::tuple` has `swap` and `operator=` as public member functions. Granted, usage cases for those scenarios are rare, but since this is an expectation of most iterators it wouldn't hurt to support it. (It's a requirement for InputIterator)

Comment: Seems reasonable, will do! Thanks so much for all of your advice! For final thoughts, what about the uniform initialization and do you think this is as close to zero cost of an abstraction as I'll get performance wise?

Comment: @BaileyParker: The problem with initialization with `()` is that the compiler is forced to treat it as a function declaration if possible: `int x();` is a function, `int x{};` a default initialized `int`. Re: zero cost abstraction: See snippet 2. It does nearly the same thing, but keeps the nestedness and thus the optimization. Unfortunately, it isn't easily composable with other algoritms.

Comment: Ah I see! I’ll work on using them instead. And I’ll dig into the godbolt when I’m in front of a larger screen. Thanks again. I really appreciate you sharing your wisdom!

Comment: @BaileyParker: It's a tradeoff between performance and usability. Unless we find a better optimizer (or a way to hint that it nestedly iterates), this tradeoff will persist. If it gives any comfort, the ranges-v3 implementation has the same issues (see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/bN3N4z))